Is there a bright line between epistemic and necessary truths?
Given my understanding of epistemic and necessary truths it seems plausible that I can construct epistemic truths using only necessary ones, which feels contradictory.
Eg 1 + 1 = 2 is a necessary truth
But 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10 is epistemic. It could very easily be wrong if I have miscounted the number of 1s.
This seems to suggest that necessary truths are just "simple to check" and that sufficiently complex necessary truths become epistemic because of a failure to check an operation.
Similarly "there are 180 degrees on the inside of a triangle" is only necessarily true in spaces such as R2. It might look necessarily true everywhere but it's not on the sphere. So what looks like a necessary truth actually an epistemic one.
What am I getting wrong?

What exactly is your understanding of "epistemic" and "necessary" truths? On the standard meanings, they are two independent properties, like red and round, epistemic truth is a knowable one and a necessary truth is one true in all possible worlds. 1 + 1 = 2 and 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10 are both epistemic and both necessary. That the Earth is round is epistemic but not necessary. We cannot give examples of non-epistemic truths because we are not supposed to know them, by definition, but realists believe that they exist.
